# Double.valueOf(Double.valueOf(json.getString("latitude")) * 1E6) instead Android Lint Prob

Tags: android, google-maps

I am getting the following warning:

Use Double.valueOf(Double.valueOf(jsonurl.getString("latitude")) * 1E6) instead    Android Lint Problem
Use Double.valueOf(Double.valueOf(jsonurl.getString("longitude")) * 1E6) instead

Issue explanation:You should not call the constructor for wrapper class directly such as newInteger(42).Instead call the "valueOf" factory method,such as Integer.valueOf((42)).this will typically use less memory.................

```
JSONObject e = arr.getJSONObject(i);
    jsonurl = (JSONObject) e.get("data");   


int jsonlng = (new Double(Double.valueOf(jsonurl.getString("longitude")) * 1E6).intValue());

newdata[i] = new GeoPoint(jsonlat,jsonlng);
```

Comment: er, then, just follow directions :)

Comment: Issue explanation:You should not call the constructor for wrapper class directly such as newInteger(42).Instead call the "valueOf" factory method,such as Integer.valueOf((42)).this will typically use less memory..................

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
int jsonlng = (int) (Double.valueOf(jsonurl.getString("longitude")) * 1E6);
```

That "(new Double(...)).intValue()" isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks fadden.I got the answer, its simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
(new Double(Double.valueOf(jsonurl.getString("longitude")) * 1E6).intValue());
```

will become

```
(Double.valueOf(Double.valueOf(jsonurl.getString("longitude")) * 1E6).intValue());
```

No Warnings.